# How can I use a color to define another color in XAML?

Tags: maui

I have got a color in a MAUI xaml, say

```
 <Color x:Key="Gray950">#141414</Color>
```

I want to define another color to be == Gray950 in xaml.
I tried several things, nothing worked. Error message during build is *Error    XFC0040 Cannot convert value "{StaticResource Gray950}" to "Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Color"*

Here two of my tries:

```
 <Color x:Key="FgColorDarkMode">{StaticResource Gray950}></Color>
 <Color x:Key="FgColorLightMode" Color="{StaticResource Gray950}"/>
```

I can use a Color in a TextColor or a BackgroundColor with such an approach:

```
<Label BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}" TextColor="{StaticResource Gray950}" />
```

But not in a color. What is wrong here?

Comment: What would be the purpose of what you're trying?

Comment: I want to use colors with speaking names in my styles. 
E.g. "TextColorDarkMode" or "BackgroundColorDarkMode"  
Those speaking names must be mapped to real colors. 
I then want to use these colors with speaking names in several Styles, e.g. Label, Button, Picker, .. 
One advantage: With this approach I could change all the BgColors at one place. At BgColorDarkMode.

Comment: Did you look into Brush: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/brushes/?view=net-maui-8.0  ?

Comment: It is an idea and will work  for backgrounds. But not so easy for foregrounds.  
In code-behind I can do label.TextColor=((SolidColorBrush)this.FindResource("MyBrush")).Color;
What is the equivalent in XAML?

Answer (score 0):

The [Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.graphics.color?view=net-maui-8.0) class is defined in the Microsoft.Maui.Graphics namespace. It doesn't have a Color property. It cannot automatically convert `Gray950` to `#141414`.

As an alternative, I will set it in code behind,

In xaml,

```
    <Color x:Key="FgColorDarkMode"/>
```

In code behind,

```
    var myColorKay = "Gray100"; // or Gray950
    var hasvalue = Resources.TryGetValue(myColorKay, out object myColor);
    this.Resources["FgColorDarkMode"] = myColor as Color;
```

Hope it helps!